# Z-index not working on IE8 where top menu falls behind left hand menu

Tags: internet-explorer-8, z-index

I'm having trouble with my top menu falling behind my left hand menu at http://www.spanish-bookworld.com/delete-spanish-books.html

I have used  for the top menu. Everything I've done to put the left hand menu behind it hasn't worked.

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it and here what should fix the problem: Try to set `z-index` on your "`#menu li`" also, not only on `div`, with "`!important`" rule in your `css.css` file, i.e:

```
#menu li {
z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Comment: bodiO, That worked like a charm. After more than three hours trying to fix the problem with all sorts of code, along comes the most elegant suggestion, and it does it. Incidentally, I haven't used !important. Is this essential?

Comment: Indeed, it is. Read more here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/

Comment: I understand now. I've added it to my .css file. You've truly made my day!

Comment: Well, one more think left to do - hit the complete answer button here ;)

Comment: I wanted to click it, but I can't see. Where is it?

Comment: Right below your question, below bottom arrow, an ugly check mark ;)